Unwanted indent in lstlisting
I am using listings to explain pieces of a code, but the PDF adds unwanted indentation. How to remove it?
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openrigt, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings} %... para escrita de códigos de programação
    \lstset{
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\tiny,        %... fonte 10pt monoespaçada
        escapechar=|,                       %... caractere de escape
        showstringspaces=false,             %... não mostrar caractere de espaço
        breaklines=true,                    %... continua o texto na próxima linha
        numbersep=5pt,                      %... distância dos números
        backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},   %... cor de fundo
        commentstyle=\color{gray},          %... estilo de comentários
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},          %... estilo de comandos
        numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},      %... estilo de numeração de linhas
        stringstyle=\color{green!75!black}, %... estilo de strings
        extendedchars=true,
        literate      =        % Support additional characters
          {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
          {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
          {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
          {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\`E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
          {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
          {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
          {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
          {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
          {ã}{{\~a}}1 {ẽ}{{\~e}}1 {ĩ}{{\~i}}1 {õ}{{\~o}}1 {ũ}{{\~u}}1
          {Ã}{{\~A}}1 {Ẽ}{{\~E}}1 {Ĩ}{{\~I}}1 {Õ}{{\~O}}1 {Ũ}{{\~U}}1
          {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1,
        morekeywords={
          subtitle,
          course,
        }
    }

\begin{document}

This is a piece of my code, written in Portuguese:
\begin{lstlisting}
Assim, o código abaixo mostra como a equação da Lei de Coulomb é apresentada a seguir: $$F = k \frac{Q \cdot q}{r^2}.$$
\end{lstlisting}
So, what is going wrong here? I mean, why is there an indent in the output PDF?


\end{document}



There's a typo in your class options: openright

If you don't want wrapped lines to be indented, you can disable this with breakindent=0pt:
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings} %... para escrita de códigos de programação
    \lstset{
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\tiny,        %... fonte 10pt monoespaçada
        escapechar=|,                       %... caractere de escape
        showstringspaces=false,             %... não mostrar caractere de espaço
        breaklines=true,                    %... continua o texto na próxima linha
        numbersep=5pt,                      %... distância dos números
        backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},   %... cor de fundo
        commentstyle=\color{gray},          %... estilo de comentários
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},          %... estilo de comandos
        numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},      %... estilo de numeração de linhas
        stringstyle=\color{green!75!black}, %... estilo de strings
        extendedchars=true,
        literate      =        % Support additional characters
          {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
          {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
          {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
          {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\`E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
          {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
          {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
          {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
          {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
          {ã}{{\~a}}1 {ẽ}{{\~e}}1 {ĩ}{{\~i}}1 {õ}{{\~o}}1 {ũ}{{\~u}}1
          {Ã}{{\~A}}1 {Ẽ}{{\~E}}1 {Ĩ}{{\~I}}1 {Õ}{{\~O}}1 {Ũ}{{\~U}}1
          {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1,
        morekeywords={
          subtitle,
          course,
        },
        breakindent=0pt
    }

\begin{document}

This is a piece of my code, written in Portuguese:
\begin{lstlisting}
Assim, o código abaixo mostra como a equação da Lei de Coulomb é apresentada a seguir: $$F = k \frac{Q \cdot q}{r^2}.$$
\end{lstlisting}
So, what is going wrong here? I mean, why is there an indent in the output PDF?


\end{document}


Works! Thank you!
